# Equation of a cubic function with inflection point on (0.5,0.5) and contains (0,0), (1,1)

Tags: cubics

The title basically summarizes my question, but the reason I'm asking this is for use as a timing function for a translation in my game.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there will be infinitely many such cubic polynomials:  $$f(x) = ax^3 - \frac{3a}{2} x^2 + \frac{a+2}{2} x$$ will satisfy the criteria $f(0) = 0$, $f(1/2) = 1/2$, $f(1) = 1$, and $f''(1/2) = 0$, for any nonzero $a$.

Comment: Thanks! a=1 works really well.

Comment: Does $f'(0.5)$ must be equal to $0$? In your case $f'(0.5) = 1-a/4$.

Comment: @AlexSilva No, if the first derivative is zero, the function has a local extremum.  It is when the second derivative is zero that there is an inflection point.

Comment: @heropup, in $f(x) = x^3$, $f'(0) = 0$ and $(0,0)$ is an inflection point. But I understand that, in this case, the sufficient condition is $f''(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
We know that 
$$f(0)=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad d=0$$
$$f(1)=1\quad\Longrightarrow \quad a+b+c+d=1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad a+b+c=1 \quad(1)$$
$$f\left(\frac 12\right)=\frac a8+\frac b4+\frac c2=\frac 12\quad (2)$$
Now, the $x$-coordinate of an inflection point of a curve is a solution of the second derivative of the curve. We have
$$f''(x)=6ax+2b=0$$
which has one solution:
$$\frac{-2b}{6a}=\frac{-b}{3a}=\frac{1}{2}\quad (3)$$
This leaves us with a system of three equations with three variables. Can you continue?